# Jupyter webpages not displaying properly

Tags: ipython, anaconda, jupyter

[Screen shot here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/r0545pspt51brcc/jupytersuks.png?dl=0).
[With Cntrl-Shift-I](https://www.dropbox.com/s/fblmmulxe1z45iq/jupytercsi.png?dl=0)

No matter how I install Jupyter(aka IPython) I get a dud webpage.  It does not display tabs or menus as expected.

The screen shot above is from a 64bit Windows Anaconda install.  It was a default install.  Install finished. No changes to configuration. First action after install was select IPython menu item in start menu.

Now, trust me, I have tried everything. I have tried installing IPython from pip over top my python2.7 installation, anaconda etc.  No matter how I install it ends up with the same problem.  I even tried 32bit installs etc.

It doesn't appear to be the browser as both IE and Chrome see the same mangled display.

It is almost like the css files are not being picked up or are not there at all.

I opted to allow the installation of the Anaconda to update my environment variables etc. so the dang blasted thing should be finding where it has put itself.

What is the likely cause?  What is the fix please?

Comment: what about inspection? Ctrl+Shift+I?

Comment: That does indeed look like it's not picking up the CSS. In the inspector, if you click on the links to the CSS files, does it find them?

Comment: Hmm.  Yep.  I looked at the inspector.  While the links are relative I assumed that they would be relative to Anaconda install so I had a peak and could everything appears under 'C:\Users\rr\Anaconda\Lib\site-packages\IPython\html'.  So it may mean (somehow) that folder path is not turning up in register OR wherever it needs to.

Comment: I tried the loader program.  It prompted me to update IPython so I tried that to see it that would fix the problem.  It did not.

Comment: I tried running ipython notebook, from the anaconda console (assuming it might set the environment) but that did not work either.

Comment: Try opening it in an incognito window to see if one of your Chrome extensions is breaking it.

Comment: @asmeurer sure.  Will try but take note that IE has same problem ... nope same problem.  Nice lateral thinking though.

Answer (score 0):

I did have a very similar issue on Windows recently. Some program has overwritten your mime type associations. For me it was Inkscape killing SVG by setting the mime type to application/svg.

Try this on terminal:

import mimetypes

mimetypes.guess('file.css')

You should get text/css. If you get application/css this is most likely your problem. My solution: Change back the mime type association. Start regedit and search for application/css in HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT. Replace it with text/css.

Please refer to this https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/7024 for further reference.